# Should a question be closed as a duplicate of a different question because the other has an answer to the "duplicate"?

Tags: discussion

Should a question be closed as a duplicate of a different question just because the other has an answer to the "duplicate"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should a question be closed as a duplicate of a different question just because the other has an answer to the "duplicate"?

Yes. That is what duplicate closing is for.

Please read [Why are some questions marked as duplicate?](https://superuser.com/help/duplicates)

You have updated your [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1250397/check-whether-a-computer-supports-wifi-direct) to state:

> It's not a duplicate.
>   The other question asks how to know if a computer supports wifi direct before buying it.

The duplicate question does not ask anything about knowing the capabilities before buying it.

It asks:

> how can I tell if a WiFi adapter supports WiFi Direct?

Which is **exactly** the same question you asked.

Comment: that doesn't answer the question of what if the question is actually a different question. The questioner may well agree that if two questions are the same i.e. , duplicates then yeah it could or should be voted closed. And you may disagree with him over whether the questions are the same But he was asking for the case where the questions are different, and you have not addressed that